# for loop to place buttons not working (Python, Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

I used a for loop to place buttons for a calculator in Tkinter. The idea is simple: every button is placed in a specific row and column, based on its value. This is the code (I wanted to make it generic):

```
for i in range(10):
    btn = tk.Button(root,
                text=str(i),
                command=lambda: expression.set(expression.get() + str(i)),
                width=10,
                height=2
                )
    row = 3 - (i - 1) // 3
    col = i % 3
    col += 3 if not col else 0
    col = col if i else 2
    btn.grid(row=row, columns=col)
    #print(f"{i}: {row}, {col}") ## Debug
    nums.append(btn)
```

Here's a screenshow of the result:

[image: Output]

I tried to print rows and columns and the output is:

```
0: 4, 2
1: 3, 1
2: 3, 2
3: 3, 3
4: 2, 1
5: 2, 2
6: 2, 3
7: 1, 1
8: 1, 2
9: 1, 3
```

Which seems okay, so I guess there's something I don't understand in Tkinter grid.

Comment: Not related to your immediate problem but change `command=lambda: ...` to `command=lambda i=i: ...`. It will save you a few min of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in this line:

```
btn.grid(row=row, columns=col)
```

`columns` (plural) is treated as a shortcut for `columnspan`. Since you don't specify the column with `column` (singular), all buttons are going in column zero with a columnspan equal to whatever is in `col`.

TL;DR: change `columns=col` to `column=col`.

Comment: Do you know why that shortcut exists? `columns` doesn't appear to be in the tcl docs. In the docs it's specified as `columnspan`. I know about the `bd`/`border` shortcut but sometimes `bd` stands for something else - I think. I don't see the point to those shortcuts.

Comment: @TheLizzard: the shortcut exists because the underlying tcl/tk interpreter supports abbreviating all options to the shortest unique string possible. You can find a mention of it in the [options](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/options.htm) man page: _"Command-line switches may be abbreviated, as long as the abbreviation is unambiguous. "_ In that context, "command-line switches" refers to options of a tk command (eg: -background, -command, etc). I don't see it mentioned anywhere in the official tkinter documentation.

Comment: Didn't know that was part of tcl but `column` and `columns` are too close imo. I am surprised that I haven't made this typo before. `colspan` and `rowspan` seem more logical abbreviations. Also `tkinter`'s official docs aren't well designed and are missing quite a bit of info.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I agree, the tkinter docs are a bit shallow. I suspect that when they first wrote them, they assumed the reader was already very familiar with tcl/tk. Also, this isn't a tcl feature, it's specific to how tk handles command options.

Comment: Welp, I will have to read more about `tk` vs `tcl` and how they handle arguments. Thx for the info.

Comment: Wow, now it works perfectly. I feel so dumb.